# Testing/Training data sets stratified on two crossed variables

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I have a data set which is crossed with respect to two categorical variables, and only 1 rep per combination:

```
> examp <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=6), class=rep(LETTERS[16:21], times=4))
> table(examp$group, examp$class)

    P Q R S T U
  A 1 1 1 1 1 1
  B 1 1 1 1 1 1
  C 1 1 1 1 1 1
  D 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to create a testing/training data set (50/50 split) which balances *both* group and class.

I know I can use `createDataPartition` from the `caret` package to balance it in one of the two factors, but this leaves impalance in the other factor:

```
> library(caret)
> examp$valid <- "test"
> examp$valid[createDataPartition(examp$group, p=0.5, list=FALSE)] <- "train"
> table(examp$group, examp$valid)

    test train
  A    3     3
  B    3     3
  C    3     3
  D    3     3
> table(examp$class, examp$valid)

    test train
  P    1     3
  Q    2     2
  R    2     2
  S    2     2
  T    2     2
  U    3     1
> 
> 
> examp$valid <- "test"
> examp$valid[createDataPartition(examp$class, p=0.5, list=FALSE)] <- "train"
> table(examp$group, examp$valid)

    test train
  A    3     3
  B    3     3
  C    5     1
  D    1     5
> table(examp$class, examp$valid)

    test train
  P    2     2
  Q    2     2
  R    2     2
  S    2     2
  T    2     2
  U    2     2
```

**How can I create a partition which is balanced in both factors?**  If I had multiple reps per group/class combination, I would stratify by `interaction(group,class)`, but I cannot in this case since there is only one observation in each combo.

Comment: Take PQR from A and B, STU from C and D?

Comment: @Gregor how's that make a half-half distribution of test/train?

Comment: Call that train, the rest is test.

Comment: @emudrak Aren't 24 data points are a little small for perfect *random* sampling?

Comment: @Gregor that's 0.25 train, 0.75 test.

Comment: @QuangHoang this is a toy data set that illustrates my problem.  The real data set has 769 data points, 49 groups and 20 classes.  In reality it is an incomplete cross due to some missing data (this is why there are not 980 data points).

Comment: @QuangHoang no it's not. Using data in the question, `train_ind = with(examp, which((group %in% c("A", "B") & class %in% c("P", "Q", "R")) | (group %in% c("C", "D") & class %in% c("S", "T", "U"))))`. `test_ind = setdiff(1:24, train_ind)`

Comment: @Gregor Yes, that is what I am just working out now.  I think this could work given that I'm going to do the test/train split 100 times...  I feel ok about it as long as I pick half of the groups at random and half of the classes at random each time...

Comment: @Gregor I'm trying to replicate the methods from a paper.   It's also not a strictly machine learning question, (the paper authors call it a "split half"), but if I phrase it as machine learning more people will understand the issue and I'll get more play for my question...  Thanks for the solution you offered- I think it will work out well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this algorithm

1. Randomly sort the unique `group` values (e.g., `DBAC`)
2. Iterate over adjacent pairs of the randomly sorted `group` values (e.g., first `DB`, then `AC`):

   1. Randomly pick half of the `class` values
   2. Assign the rows with the first `group` and in the selected half of `class` to `TRAIN`
   3. Assign the rows with the second `group` and *not* in the selected half of `class` to `TEST`